# Dart function in a function

Tags: function, dart, closures

My Code:

```
void main() {
  String name() {
    return "Uday Kiran";
  }

  void printF(var value) {
    print(value);
  }

  printF(name);
}
```

Hey, I'm sorry if my question is silly. But I'm probably new to the programming and I stuck by doing something like this. I actually wanted to pass the string returned by the name function, as a argument to my printF function, so that the string "Uday Kiran" would be printed on my console. But the output I get is something like this:

[image]

- Any help would be appreciable:)

Comment: You are not calling the method but are referring to it as a `Function`. You call a method with `()` so you need to do e.g.: `printF(name());`. Also `printF(var value)` is not really a great method signature since you are then allowing every type as argument instead of restricting to e.g. `String`.

Comment: Hey, buddy thanks that worked. And thanks for your suggestion in declaring the function's parameter.

Comment: Ok, I will write an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are refer to `name` as a variable which points to a `Function` instead of calling the function it points to. In Dart, you call a function with `()` (in case of no arguments) so your example should instead be:

```
void main() {
  String name() {
    return "Uday Kiran";
  }

  void printF(String value) {
    print(value);
  }

  printF(name());
}
```

I also changed the type of `argument` to specify you want to get a `String` as argument as stated in your question. By doing so, you would also got an error explaining the problem with `name` in your example.